# add error code to normal page?

Tags: error-code

Is it possible to add, for example error code 404, ***to a completely normal page***, so visitors (bots and crawlers) register the page as "not found" (or other error codes)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying that.  Why are you considering it?

Comment: Yes. But I can't think of a single good reason to do it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller messing with bots :) - it's a private site, so I don't need any google bots there ither..

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I can.. that's why I asked!

Comment: @AdamLarsson Depending on your server software, you'll likely want to use its "custom 404 page" functionality to set different custom 404 pages for different paths. That seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister well, then it's a 404 page,  want it on all my pages, there must be some kind of metadata you can enter in the page?

Comment: @AdamLarsson 404 can’t be controlled by page metadata or any part of the HTML. It’s an HTTP header that needs to be set by the server software. How to do that depends on the server software you’re using.

Comment: If it is private and you don't want search engines to index it you have better options like password protecting it or using `noindex` meta tags.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller password, not suitable here, and since when does bad bots read the noindex tag?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I'm running on Apache.

Comment: You are hoping that the bad bots will see the 404 and give up?   I highly doubt that.